# Animação com CSS: controlar que elemento respeite os limites de tamanho da tela

Tags: css, css3

Fiz uma animação básica de uma `div` que oscila entre o lado esquerdo e direito da tela por tempo indeterminado. Ocorre que ao chegar ao extremo direito da tela, a `div` ultrapassa o campo visível fazendo com que parte dela desapareça. Gostaria que a `div` respeitasse o tamanho da tela e nunca ultrapassasse 100%. Não posso usar 95% em `left`, pois o percentual vai variar de acordo com a resolução do usuário. Preciso que seja preciso para qualquer resolução.

Segue o fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xt9zc6c/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes anima{
    0%{
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }   
    50%{
        top: 0px;
        left: 100%;
    }
    100%{
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
}
#circle{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: anima 8s infinite;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="circle"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução inicial foi colocar um *container* para limitar a ação do objeto:

```css
@keyframes anima{
    0%{ left: 0; } 
   50%{ left: 100%;}
  100%{ left: 0; }
}

#container {
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:40px;
  border:1px solid green;
}

#circle{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: anima 8s infinite;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
 <div id="circle"></div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Aproveitei e dei uma ajustada no CSS. Quando você põe um valor zero, não deve especificar unidades.

A explicação é a seguinte: da forma que você fez a animação, o que está sendo animado é o canto superior esquerdo do objeto, então 100% significa que a margem esquerda estará no limite da tela (consequentemente o objeto estará para fora).

Colocando um *padding* do lado direito, da mesma largura do objeto, estamos compensando o tamanho deste.

A borda verde é apenas para você poder visualizar a animação funcionando corretamente. As margens que sobram em volta do *container* são do `body`, não tirei no CSS de exemplo, mas basta acrescentar no seu CSS uma regra para removê-las.

Para finalizar, o `box-sizing:border-box;` faz com que nosso *container* de 100% de largura considere 100% incluindo o *padding* que inserimos na medida (e até a borda verde).

### Evoluindo a idéia

Depois de uma conversa nos comentários, em que o autor perguntou da possibilidade de se ter uma solução onde não tenha que se saber de antemão o tamanho do padding, cheguei a uma conclusão mais limpa, que não depende de container, e se ajusta ao tamanho do objeto:

```css
@keyframes anima{
  0%{ left:0;transform:translateX(0); } 
  50%{ left:100%;transform:translateX(-100%); }
  100%{ left:0;transform:translateX(0); }
}

#ball1, #ball2 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left:0;
  transform:translateX(0);
  animation: anima 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

#ball2 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}

body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="ball1"></div>  
  <div id="ball2"></div>  
</body>
```

O truque aqui foi mexer no pivô da animação, que vai do ponto superior esquerdo até o superior direito, usando `translate()`, para que ao chegar na margem direita o objeto não saia da tela.

Aproveitei para alterar as medidas para simular a tela cheia sem borda, com o elemento realmente tocando nas margens.

Comment: ok entendi. Agora me responda uma coisa, na qual inicialmente estava pensando e não coloquei na pergunta. E se o tamanho da bola vermelha fosse dinâmico, isto é, se o width e height fossem variáveis (controlados por javascript ou no servidor), existe alguma solução na qual eu não preciso definir o padding-right:40px? Isso seria interessante pois teria uma solução mais genérica.

Comment: É bem diferente essa demanda da proposta da pergunta original. Vou dar uma pensada aqui. Se bem que se for controlar por JS ou pelo servidor, basta mudar as propriedades nos dois lugares, não? (tanto no objeto quanto no container)

Comment: o tamanho da bola seria mudada programaticamente via JS. Aí teria que mudar programaticamente o padding-right também... acho que funciona. Mas ficaria mais "clean" se tivesse alguma forma de deixar isso em CSS puro.

Comment: pensei em usar a função calc() do css, mas não sei se seria possível nesse contexto

Comment: @Maigret acho que resolvi.

Comment: show! agora ficou top.

Answer (score 1):

Basta acrescentar um `margin-left: -40px`, já que o `#circle` tem um `width: 40px`.

Funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/3xt9zc6c/1/

```css
@keyframes anima{
    0%{
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }   
    50%{
        top: 0px;
        left: 100%;
        margin-left: -40px;
    }
    100%{
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
}
#circle{
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
-webkit-animation: anima 8s infinite;
-moz-animation: anima 8s infinite;
animation: anima 8s infinite;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
    <div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: o animate parou de funcionar, ele não faz a animação de modo contínuo.

Comment: No meu caso funciona, se estiver usando o Google Chrome, tente acrescentar outro `animation`, desta vez sem o `-webkit-`.

Comment: mas já não é o mesmo resultado. A animação fica binária, o círculo começa na esquerda e logo depois pula para a direita, sem fazer a transição de forma gradual.

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma possível solução.